# Are principal congruence subgroups ever surface groups?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, geometric-topology

Define the principal congruence subgroup of level $ n $, $ \Gamma(n) $, to be the subgroup of $ PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $ which is congruent to the identity mod $ n $. $ \Gamma(n) $ is discrete infinite, and torsion free.

A (Fuchsian) surface group is also a discrete infinite and torsion free group of 2 by 2 matrices.

Are there any $ n $ for which $ \Gamma(n) $ is a surface group (isomorphic to the fundamental group of a surface)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ has a free subgroup $F$ of finite index. If $\Gamma(n)$ was a surface group $G$, then $G$ would have a free subgroup $G\cap F$ of finite index. However every finite index subgroup of a surface group is a surface group itself possibly of different genus. Of course I assume that by "surface group" you mean the fundamental group of a closed surface.

Comment: In general does this show that there are no surface groups in $ PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $?

Comment: Yes, it does. Every subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ has a free subgroup of finite index.

Comment: About your last question.  According to at least one definition of a Fuchsian group, a subgroup of a Fuchsian group is Fuchsian, so the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make myself clear.  What I'm trying to ask is the following. Let $ \Gamma $ be a subgroup of $ PSL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ which is isomorphic to the fundamental group of a compact genus $ g $ surface with $ g \geq 2 $. Is the intersection $ \Gamma \cap  PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $ necessarily just the identity?

Comment: The intersection is $\Gamma$.

Comment: sorry that was a typo the $ PSL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ in the last line was supposed to be  $ PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $

Comment: Then the intersection may be a non-trivial free group.

Comment: oh that's very interesting! Would you happen to have an example a surface group intersecting nontrivially with $  PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $  that you could put in your answer or a comment?

Comment: I do not want to give a non-optimal proof. I have asked a specialist who should know. It is probably published somewhere. I suspect that every non-torsion element of $PSL_2(\mathbb R)$ is in a surface subgroup.

Comment: The experts responded. In fact every hyperbolic element of $PSL_2(\mathbb R)$ is contained in a surface subgroup. That is because  any two hyperbolic elements with the same translation length are conjugate. For example there is a surface subgroup containing the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 2 &1 \\1&1\end{pmatrix}$. If $G$ is a surface subgroup containing this matrix, then $G\cap PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is infinite.

Comment: Here is a more detailed proof. Choose a hyperbolic element $f$. It has translation length $t$. You can then take any hyperbolic surface with a simple closed curve of length $t$. (This is possible by hyperbolic geometry). The surface subgroup $G$ will have a hyperbolic element $g$ with translation length $t$. Take any hyperbolic isometry sending the axis of $f$ to the axis of $g$. Conjugating $G$ by this isometry gives you your surface group containing $f$.

Comment: Thanks so much! You've gone above and beyond and I'm grateful for your help.  The next question I was going to post to MSE is given $ g \geq 2 $ is there a good way to find real algebraic numbers $ b_1, \dots b_k $ such that $ \pi_1(\Sigma_g) $ can be embedded in $ PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}[b_1, \dots, b_k]) $ For example, is there some way to, given $ g $, find a prime $ p $ such that $ \pi_1(\Sigma_g) $ embeds in $ PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}[cos(2\pi/p), sin(2\pi/p)]) $. If this expert of yours is taking more questions I would love to get an opinion!